# Install Ubu7ntu 14.04.1 over 14.10

Tags: system-installation

What should I do ?  I am running UBUNTU 14.10 now,  but I want to have 14.04.1.  Now I have downloaded this iso file and burned it on DVD.  Should I first wipe my SSD or can I install it over the 14.10 Version ?

Comment: You could wipe your entire SSD if you don't have any essential data in it. After wiping the SSD, you could install a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 as usual you did with any Ubuntu before.

Comment: Well I know this problem,  I've had this myself and I wiped my whole SSD and installed everything new.  Just be shore to take your Ubunto 14.04.1 and create an iso - immage first.  I used Brasero.  This Burning tool is available in the Software Center.  After Burning an Immage you can wipe your SSD and load the DVD with Ubuntu 14.04.1 iso.  Then you're done !!!